# How to cut away parts of an object below a plane

Tags: modifiers, geometry

I'm trying to make a beach scene with a fluid sim. I have a plane that i've sculpted as the sand, and then a cube that fills the domain as the water source, and I want to cut away any part of the cube that is below the sand so it wont spawn water in there.

Here is an image of my current setup to give you an idea of what I mean.
[image]

I feel like this should be doable with a boolean modifier but I can't seem to get it to work as it will only cut away the part of the cube that the plane is touching.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use a *Boolean Modifier* on the cube set to *Difference*. Set the target to be your "Sand" plane (it says Cube.001 in my image because I made the plane from dupllicating the bottom face of the cube and then making it a separate object). If the bool operation tries to  delete the wrong part of the cube, select the whole "sand" plane in edit mode and then select *Mesh > Normals > Flip* from the menu at the top of the viewport:

[image: Bool]

Comment: I just tried this but it didnt give me the result your getting. I ended up with the only part left being the part that intersects with the plane

Comment: @SantasSpy It will help if your plane is slightly larger than the cube, so it sticks out on all sides